# Using QueryFullProcessImageNameA to check for running processes when going to 64-bit

Tags: delphi, process, delphi-11-alexandria

When converting a 32 bit app to 64 bit (Alexandria 11.3) I noted this code:

```
type
  TQueryFullProcessImageNameA = function(hProcess: THandle; dwFlags: DWord; lpExeName: PAnsiChar; lpdwSize: PDWord): Bool; stdcall;
const
  QueryFullProcessImageNameA: TQueryFullProcessImageNameA = nil;
  PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = $1000;
var
  Kernel32Lib: HMODULE;

Initialization
   Kernel32Lib := GetModuleHandle(kernel32);
   QueryFullProcessImageNameA := GetProcAddress(Kernel32Lib, 'QueryFullProcessImageNameA');
```

This is then used in

```
function IsProcessRunning(AFileName: string; AIncludePath : Boolean = False): Boolean;
var
  PIDList          : array[0..1023] of THandle;
  i                : integer;
  ListCount, size  : cardinal;
  hProcess, hModule: THandle;
  ModuleName       : array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
  lFileName        : string;
  AnsiModuleName   : Ansistring;
  Len              : DWORD;
begin
  Result:= False;

  if not AIncludePath then
     AFileName := ExtractFileName(AFileName);

  // PSAPI.DLL required
  if not EnumProcesses(@PIDList, sizeof(PIDList), ListCount) then Exit;

  ListCount:= ListCount div sizeof(THandle);

  for i:= 0 to ListCount-1 do
  begin

    if assigned(QueryFullProcessImageNameA) then 
    begin
       hProcess:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, PIDList[i]); 

       try
          if hProcess <> 0 then
          begin
             Len := MAX_PATH;
             SetLength(AnsiModuleName, Len-1);
             if QueryFullProcessImageNameA( hProcess, 0, PAnsiChar(AnsiModuleName), @Len) then
             begin
                SetLength(AnsiModuleName, Len);
                lFileName := string(AnsiModuleName);
             end;
          end;
       finally
         CloseHandle(hProcess);
       end;

    end
    else // Before Vista (XP)
    begin

       // get process handle for each process id we got
       hProcess:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION + PROCESS_VM_READ, false, PIDList[i]);

       try
         if hProcess <> 0 then
         begin

           // get handle to first module, which is the exe
           if EnumProcessModules(hProcess, @hModule, sizeof(hModule), size) then
           begin
             // extract the filename
             GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hModule, ModuleName, sizeof(ModuleName));

             lFileName := ModuleName;

           end;
         end;
       finally
         CloseHandle(hProcess);
       end;
    end;

    if (not AIncludePath) then
       lFileName := ExtractFileName(lFileName);

    if CompareText(lFileName, AFileName) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := true;
      Exit;
    end;

  end; //For listcount
end;
```

Is this still allowed and useful under 64 bit?

Do I have to look for running processes differently if IsProcessRunning() is used for 32 and/or 64 bit apps?

If it is different for 64 bit, how?

Comment: The code should be using `QueryFullProcessImageNameW` instead, in both 32bit and 64bit (and, I would consider using Delphi's built-in [`delayed`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio//en/Libraries_and_Packages_(Delphi)#Delayed_Loading_.28Windows-only.29) feature instead). Other than that, I don't see any reason why the code wouldn't work under 64bit.